# doubt with an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations

I was reading this exercise:
If $x=\frac{a}{b+c}=\frac{b}{a+c}=\frac{c}{a+b}$, then the value of $x$ is?
Solution:
When $a+b+c\not =0$, from the given equalities we have
$$a=(b+c)x, \,\,\, b=(a+c)x\, \, \, c=(a+b)x.$$
By adding them up, we obtain $2(a+b+c)x=a+b+c$, so $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
Since $b+c\not =0$, $a+c\not =0$, $a+b\not =0$, if one $a,b,c$ is $0$, then, from the given equalities, the other two are zeros also, a contradiction. Therefore $abc\not =0$

When $a+b+c=0$, then $b+c=-a$, $a+c=-b$, $a+b=-c$, so
$$x=\frac{a}{b+c}=\frac{b}{a+c}=\frac{c}{a+b}=-1$$.

I have doubts regarding this solution, do you think it is correct? I mean this in the sense that the exercise does not prevent me or says as a condition that $a\not =b \not =c\not =a$.

Comment: Looks OK to me. For instance, $a=b=c=1$ gives $x = \frac{1}{2}$, while $a=1$, $b=1$, and $c=-2$ gives $x=-1$.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, but you may want to (prove and) add that the solution $x=1/2$ in the case $a+b+c \ne 0$ case only exists when $a=b=c\ne 0$.